# Vue Firebase cannot not fetch image url after uploading image

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

```
createMeetup({ commit, getters }, payload) {
  const meetup = {
    title: payload.title,
    location: payload.location,
    desciption: payload.desciption,
    date: payload.date.toISOString(),
    creatorId: getters.user.id
  };
  let imageUrl;
  let key;
  firebaseApp
    .database()
    .ref("meetups")
    .push(meetup)
    .then(data => {
      key = data.key;
      return key;
    })
    .then(key => {
      const filename = payload.image.name;
      const ext = filename.slice(filename.lastIndexOf("."));
      return firebaseApp
        .storage()
        .ref("meetups/" + key + "." + ext)
        .put(payload.image);
    })
    .then(fileData => {
      // TODO: Image ref not found
      imageUrl = fileData.ref.getDownloadURL();
      return firebaseApp
        .database()
        .ref("meetups")
        .child(key)
        .update({ imageUrl: imageUrl });
    })
    .then(() => {
      commit("createMeetup", {
        ...meetup,
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        id: key
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
},
```

After the TODO part of giving an error. I think it provides promise but cannot figure out how to deal with it. The error is Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "src". Expected String, Object, got Promise

Answer (score 0):

[getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getdownloadurl) returns a promise, not a string.  You need to use the promise to get the URL asynchronously, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url).

```
...
    .then(fileData => {
      return fileData.ref.getDownloadURL();
    })
    .then(imageUrl => {
      return firebaseApp
        .database()
        .ref("meetups")
        .child(key)
        .update({ imageUrl: imageUrl });
    })
...
```